# controlling spacing between lines in tree of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, line-spacing, tocloft

Since yesterday I have learned that doing a hard reset on a git branch also throws away stashed changes. So, I need to recreate some steps that I have inadvertently thrown away. Unfortunately I cannot remember how I decreased the spacing between lines of contents table. I have tried

```
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecafterpnum}{\vspace{-8pt}}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsubsecafterpnum}{\vspace{-8pt}}
```

which works, but unfortunately I also have the custom defined `subsubsubsection` which I am unable to modify using the above logic using `tocloft` package.

I have also tried

```
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{0.8}\normalsize
\tableofcontents
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.0}\normalsize
```

but this controls only the space of multilines in TOC.

Below are images of what I have now and what it used to look like. Any hints on how to decrease spacing between the lines would be much appreciated.

This is "before" look of how I managed to decrease the spacing.
[image]

This is what it looks now.
[image]

Comment: `subsubsubsection` is no level by default for most document classes, so `tocloft` can not get grip of this level with its `\cftX....` macros. You have must either change `\l@subsubsubsection` or provide `\newlistentry`, which will lead to a problem, most likely, since you might have defined a counter named `subsubsubsection`, which `\newlistentry` tries to define again. Since you have not posted working code, it is hard to tell which solution works best and 99% is guessing only

Comment: Perhaps `\subsubsubsection` is nothing different than `\paragraph` and you should change `\cftparaafterpnum` instead

Comment: @ChristianHupfer sorry for the lack of MWE, I was hoping there is something obvious I've missed. However, due to my inability to get this working for hours I sense that it's not as trivial as I remember. In any case, if you'd like to get the thing running, I can offer you [this repo](https://github.com/romunov/duhturat/tree/cd1b63e5aecd39bdec807230797013a6e296e278/teza_biroshit/teza) for now. If you're on Windows, you can just run runlatex.bat.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer the `\cftparaafterpnum` worked. Good guess. :) Please post this as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: I am not working on Windows, but looking into your `runlatex.bat` I noticed that you remove any auxiliary file before and then recompile three times, which might be unnecessary when not removing the additional files...

Comment: Which document class do you employ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are not really many classes/packages that provide support for `\subsubsubsection` and as such, `tocloft` and its `\cftX...` macros cannot configure contentline entries regarding the sectioning level `subsubsubsection`.

Either `subsubsubsection` has to be enabled with something like `\newlistentry` or `\subsubsubsection` is most likely nothing different than `\paragraph`, so changing the relevant `\cftpara...` values helps (as it apparently does in the case of this O.P.)